# JS - Regular Expression for 12hr Time Matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to take this regular expression that is currently being used in a java application and use it with javascript.

```
(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)
```

However, I am running into issues. I was initially getting a `SyntaxError: invalid quantifier` error. So I escaped the `?` and ended up with

```
(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\s)?(\?i)(am|pm)
```

However, when I run the following test, it is not matching properly:

```
"1:00 am".match(/(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\s)?(\?i)(am|pm)/)
```

This regex should be matching “1:00am”, “1:00 am”, ”1:00 AM”

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something; what does this part do?: "(\?i)". It seems to mean that it is literally looking for "?i" in your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
"1:00 am".match(/(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\s?(am|pm)/i)
```

The ignore case flag `i` should be at the end of the regex

Comment: Ah, that did it. Learn something new every day. Thank you.